# Are $\mathbb{Q}(π)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(π^2)$ the same field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers, ring-homomorphism

I've tried to check if $\mathbb{Q}(π)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(π^2)$ are equal fields.

I know there exists a field isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(π)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(π^2)$ since $π$ and $π^2$ are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I also know that $π^2 = π\cdot π$, but I can't see the other implication to get the equality.

Thanks.

Comment: Since $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, you cannot have $\pi \in \mathbb Q(\pi^2)$

Comment: Notice someone edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. We edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 7):

If $L/K$ is a field extension and $x \in L$ is trancendental over $K$, then $K(x^2)$ is a *proper* subfield of $K(x)$. In fact, otherwise $x \in K(x^2)$, so that we get an equation $x=f(x^2)/g(x^2)$ with $f,g \in K[T]$ (with $g \neq 0$). Then $x  \cdot g(x^2)=f(x^2)$ and hence, since $x$ is transcendental, $T \cdot g(T^2)=f(T^2)$. The left side has odd degree, the right side even degree, contradiction.

Actually, a much stronger statement holds: When $p \in K(x) \setminus K$, then $K(x)$ is finite over $K(p)$, and the degree is $\max(\deg(p_1),\deg(p_2))$ when $p = p_1/p_2$ with coprime $p_1,p_2 \in K[T]$. Thus, we have $K(x)=K(p)$ iff $\max(\deg(p_1),\deg(p_2))=1$, which means that $p_1,p_2$ are constant or linear, where one has to be linear.